# generate new cryptokey for each instance of downloadable package (Xamarin and C#)

Tags: c#, android, encryption, xamarin

I want to produce a Xamarin Android App which will communicate via a secure HTTPS link to a web service.  To add to the security the data will be encrypted via a symmetrical encryption process.  This requires a shared key at the app and at the service.

I obviously don't want to use the same key for each and every instance of the app - so this needs to be generated on a one per download basis and retained at the server end.

I have considered the following options

1. Use a shared common key once only to download a unique key for the app instance.
2. Include a unique Key in the config file (but how do to this?)
3. Include it in the C# body of code and again - how to do this?

So a simple requirement - each and every download (which can be from a controlled server so we can make changes prior to downloading) needs to produce a unique key - make that available to the app and store it somewhere at the server - along with a common identifier.

Comment: Why do you think you need this?  Why is HTTPS not enough?

Comment: If there is a generic system for reading https signals in the future (or one that exists now) then this will add an additional task complexity to reading these messages; just as a salt does to a normal encryption.  I am not fooling myself or anyone else that this will be unbreakable, I just want to be in a position that shows that all reasonable precautions were taken.

Comment: You don't "salt an encryption", you salt hashes :) personally I don't think the time you spend implementing this will be worth it, and rolling your own would be a poor idea, but you will need to transmit the unique key to the app when it is first run from your server. Which would require HTTPS in the first place. Or you could use RSA to get the key there. So you either use HTTPS or reinvent HTTPS.

Comment: Well no, not really.  A salt was used to protect against rainbow attacks and similar by making it more difficult to pattern match.  If I can provide a shared key which is different for each and every download of the product that means that some bad chappie can't simply intercept the communications at the https protocol and say "job done".  They will still have the additional task of breaking the symmetrical key.  This is not re-inventing anything, it is taking two different processes to make it more difficult to read different peoples data.  (otherwise 1 break gives access to everyone's data)

Comment: Salts still are used to protect against rainbow tables, you are correct.  But rainbow tables attack hashes, not encryption.  I'm just trying to further your knowledge, not be rude! :) Additionally, if you could "intercept communications at the HTTPS protocol" then we wouldn't have online banking etc.  I think you may have misunderstood what I meant about reinventing as well.  To get the key to your app, you will need to pretty much reinvent HTTPS in the first place (e.g. RSA asymmetric to transmit the symmetric key).

Comment: That would be option 1.  There are still options 2 and 3 and variants thereupon.  No re-invention is necessary - sending encrypted data over https is not unusual

Comment: If you assume HTTPS is broken, the exchange of the key you are going to use symmetrically is going to be compromised too. Hence, your idea already at this point is insecure.

Comment: Either I wrote this unclearly or there is a misunderstanding there.  The key is generated and stored in the database.  It is included in the download by some unclear means - the question asked.  There is no exchange of keys as both parties already have them.

Comment: For further information as to why separate encryption for each user is required see: https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2017/03/the_cias_develo.html  (DO NOT solely rely on SSL/TLS to secure data in transit.

Rationale: Numerous man-in-middle attack vectors and publicly disclosed flaws in the protocol.
)